# Spring Boot controller does not redirect

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, controller

I create the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "redirect:resources/templates/login.html";
    }
}
```

But, trying to map this endpoint, I receive 404-ERROR. 
This is a target-page location:
[image: path]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Static contents inside **resources** will be added to class-path directly. Remove **resources** from URL

Comment: tried this "redirect:templates/login.html". And this "redirect:/templates/login.html". But with the same result

Answer (score 1):

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLoginPage() {
    return "login";
}
```

It works to me.I hope hepls you!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLoginPage() {
    return "login.html";
}
```

This will work

Comment: I does not work. May be I have to put InternalResourceViewResolver in project-configuration?

Comment: It's not necessary. You can remove the ".html".